# Как сделать Сookie доступным на всех страницах сайта?

Tags: php, cookie

Есть две страницы, например, `site1.com/1/` и `site.com/2/`.

На странице 1 устанавливаются куки:

```
SetCookie("CookieName",$date,time()+60*60*24*1);
```

На странице 2 вывожу:

```
echo $_COOKIE['CookieName'];
```

Но значение cookie не выводится. Хотя если выводить на странице 1, то работает.
Как правильно записывать и выводить куки, чтобы они были доступны на всех страницах сайта?

Comment: Один я вижу, что домены у сайтов разные?

Comment: @Виктор, Роман прав, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно установить параметру `$path` значение `'/'`:

```
SetCookie("CookieName", $date, time()+60*60*24*1, '/');
```

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php):

> `path` — Путь к директории на сервере, из которой будут доступны cookie. Если задать `'/'`, cookie будут доступны во всем домене domain. Если задать `'/foo/'`, cookie будут доступны только из директории `/foo/` и всех ее поддиректорий (например, `/foo/bar/`) домена. **По умолчанию значением является текущая директория, в которой cookie устанавливается.**

Answer (score 3):

С куками в РНР работать точно так же, как с любыми другими технологиями: путем внимательного прочтения документации на используемую функцию, доступной по очень простому и короткому адресу php.net/setcookie

Путем оного прочтения можно узнать, что у функции есть параметр path -

> Путь к директории на сервере, из которой будут доступны cookie. Если
>   задать '/', cookie будут доступны во всем домене domain. Если задать
>   '/foo/', cookie будут доступны только из директории /foo/ и всех ее
>   поддиректорий (например, /foo/bar/) домена domain. По умолчанию
>   значением является текущая директория, в которой cookie
>   устанавливается.